# nodejs: async - what is the difference between Promise.then() and await?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, synchronization

I am new to nodejs, and while familiar with the basic concepts of async programming, I don't have much on-hand experience writing async code.

I am writing a simple web-app that will connect to a DB using sequelize. Getting started I used their example code (https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/getting-started/):

```
try {
  await sequelize.authenticate();
  console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
}
```

which leads to the error: `await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`. Leveraging the little knowledge I have I changed my code to:

```
Promise.resolve().then(async () => {
  await sequelize.authenticate();
  console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
}).catch(error => {
  console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
});
```

Which works as expected. But as far as I can tell, both versions of my code are essentially exactly the same (except that the first example is much more simple and appealing to me readability-wise)

What am missing? why can't I use `await` in my first example and what is "top level bodies of modules" mean anyway?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't use await in the first example is that the code block where (try...catch) is present is not inside an async function. Wait can only be used inside async functions, which are declared using the async keyword.

The phrase "top level bodies of modules" refers to the context in which the code runs. In Node.js, code outside any function or code block is considered "top-level". However, using await outside of an async function is only allowed in a module body (file), not in the global context or regular function body.

In summary, you can only use wait inside async functions. In the first example, because the block of code is not inside an async function, it must be wrapped in a promise or moved inside an async function in order to use await.Wrap everything in an async function, it should work.

Comment: okay... but suppose I do put it in an async function.. then if I want to use it (the async function) I am stuck again in square one.. is there a proper way to call an async function from the "top-level" of my app?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but you'll call the function with function name plus the two parentheses.                                                                  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function